# Subplot with decomposed morphological structuring element

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mathematical-morphology

I am using MATLAB 2014b, so the function `strel` behaves in a slightly different way respect to the newer versions<sup>[1]</sup>. In any case, I am generating a `disk` shaped structuring element by an approximation of 8 (in reality 10) linear structuring elements.

I would like to **visualize these linear structuring elements**, for example in a subplot. Unfortunately, after all these years using MATLAB, I still have many problems understanding how to obtain what I want from a plot. In this case I would just be able to visualize them with a "comparable" scale, so that one can notice the differences in size and orientation. (Note: I am using `imcomplement` to get black lines on white background, instead of the opposite, for printing reasons.)

The minimal code is this:

```
se = strel('disk', 300, 8);
seq = getsequence(se);

for k = 1:length(seq)
    subplot(5,2,k);
    imshow(imcomplement(seq(k).getnhood));
    axis equal
end
```

As you can see, it results in a suboptimal subplot:

[image]

So to summarize, the question is: **is it possible to obtain a visualization** (either a subplot, or 10 different plots) **where the strels have roughly the same scale**, and they are visible enough so that a reader can get the idea of how this decomposition works?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In MATLAB 2014b to obtain the neighborhood of a structuirng element you have to use the method `getnhood`, while in newer versions you just have to access the field `Neighborhood`.

Comment: If you make sure that every image is the same size before you plot, that will work

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think about padding the smaller images.. I am a bit burned out at the moment!